# Change widget visibility using QCheckBox or QComboBox in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to show/hide a `QLineEdit` (or some other widget) using `QCheckBox` or `QComboBox`.

Comment: Improve the title of the question, it is very general. It also shows what you have tried. read [ask]

Answer (score 4):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

class GUI(Qt.QWidget):     

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.lineEdit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Hello Hossam Almasto")
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.combo = Qt.QComboBox(self) #, activated = self.onChangeDir)
        self.combo.addItem("Test 1")
        self.combo.addItem("Test 2")
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

    def onActivated(self, text):
        self.comboText = text        
        if self.comboText == "Test 2":
            self.lineEdit.hide()
        else:
            self.lineEdit.show()
            self.combo.setFocus()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    mw  = GUI()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks @S.Nck this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the `stateChanged` signal (for `QCheckBox`; emitted every time you check/uncheck the box) or `currentIndexChanged` signal (for `QComboBox`; emitted every time you select a different item in the combo box) to a slot (you can also use a `lambda` here). In that slot all you need to do is call the `QLineEdit`'s `show()` or `hide()` method to toggle the visibility of the line edit.

Comment: I used currentIndexChange but it's work only for the first change

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Please provide the code so that we can see what you have done so far and what needs to be fixing.